# populating a map with GET API call results

Tags: bash, associative-array

I have a script that returns a number of uuids that I want to put in a map. However, looks like when I run this script, it only populates my map with the first value out of the whole uuid list. What am I doing wrong? hydra_get_fileshares is a pre-defined function that calls a GET API to get a list of uuids. Also, I am using bash 3

```
nodes=($(hydra_get_fileshares | jq --raw-output '.values[].id'))
for d in "${nodes[@]}"; do
    ARRAY=( "d:${d}")
done
```

Comment: `ARRAY+=( "d:${d}")`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although I would parse the output of your command directly with a `while read` loop and [ProSub](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Process-Substitution.html).

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

while IFS= read -r d; do
  array+=("d:$d")
done < <(hydra_get_fileshares | jq --raw-output '.values[].id')
```

The `+=` with the array assignment was a work around/solution before anyone can even say `mapfile` aka `readarray` which is not part of bashv3.

Quoting the bash manual under the *PARAMETERS* section.

> In the context where an assignment statement is assigning a value to a shell variable or array index, the *+=* operator can be used to append to  or  add  to  the variable's  previous  value

Comment: Thanks,then how to iterate over "array" to read map values?

Comment: Outside the `while read` loop use a `for loop` to loop through the `"${array[@]}"`

Comment: But I have a feeling that you're looking for an `associative array` , which is not  a feature of bashv3 either....